# Manipulating CSV Duplicates

Tags: csv, sorting

I'm working on my webshop and I've found out there are many combinations I need to sort.

I need to find all name duplicates and name them with the same ID number.
I'm using a program called CSVed but any other program will do.

[image: This is what it looks like right now.]

[image: And this is what i need it to be,]

All duplicates get the same ID code
It does not matter what number they get, they only need to be the same.

It would save me hours maybe days of work if someone knows a tip or tool to sort this.

Comment: This is a relative straight forward problem with a programming language like `Python`.  I am assuming that these sorts of solutions are not an option for you.

Comment: I really have no clue what you just said

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved. The solution is, Use excel and remove all duplicates. then make a new colomn with random numbers next to it.  Then use the VLOOKUP command and thats pretty much it !